Identify that Sci-Fi movie I watched between 1979 and 1982
I was a kid when I saw it on TV, so I remember only very few things.
The movie was about population control. A company invents a device that can be implanted in someone's head, around the temple if I remember.
The device looked like some stick, not very different that RFID tags used today for animals, but just much larger.
People are somehow supposed to have that stick implanted; if I remember well, it made "the society work well and everyone is happy" type of deal.
The people that have the stick will notice those that do not have it and the crowd will them walk toward them to encircle them, similarly to the invasion of the body snatchers.
Toward the end of the movie, the guy that invented the device is in his office, on top of his tower, and he somehow realizes his mistake watching someone getting 'converted' through a camera showing the plaza below and tells some people that are with him, and without the device, that the only place they'll be safe will be this office.
I think he dies at this point since he had some disease that made him get old fast, but I don't recall in detail.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

I was 8-9 years old, so there is only the date range I provided above; I was too young to think about countries of origin or notice that. What I wrote is pretty much all I remember

But you know the language it was in...right?. It's amazing how much information you think you don't know until you're prompted.

I was in France at the time, but all movies are fully dubbed in French due to the 'protect the language no matter what' laws, so the origin could really be anywhere. That being said, in those days sci-fi I saw was almost 100% from the US. We had a B&W TV back then, so I don't know if the movie was in color, but it didn't have an 'old' feel at all; with what I know today of movies and the feeling left from that one, I'd say it was a 70s movie from the US, but it's really an impression.

One thing that may matter: at that time, France had the movies about 2 years after they'd come out in the US, and I saw it roughly at the same time as Westworld; but it had to be a re-run since I was born in 1972.

Unfortunately, when you saw it doesn't help much unless it was a new release at the time.

That sounds similar to Logan's Run? However, the implant was a crystal the hand not the head, and there was population control:  http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0074812/synopsis?ref_=ttpl_pl_syn

I know Logan's run, it was definitely not like it; it was a lot darker. The one thing I remember now is that while the world was getting converted by force to the device, the inventor's close friends were against it and were never converted since the movie had them arguing about it.
